# How to hide change tracking in MS Word Starter?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-starter

I received a docx document that was edited with change-tracking enabled. Opening it for viewing with Word 2010 Starter, I see the changes in their bubbles. According to the help, in this edition I cannot turn the change tracking on or off. But, can I turn the *tracking preview* off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Microsoft themselves: [Word features that are not fully supported in Word Starter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/starter-help/word-features-that-are-not-fully-supported-in-word-starter-HA010374498.aspx)

> **Change tracking**:  If you open a document that was changed while the Track Changes feature was turned on, you will see editing marks in the document. You cannot accept or reject the changes, and you cannot turn change tracking on or off in Word Starter.

Answer (score 6):

Stumbled upon blatantly simple solution:
Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C, New Document, Ctrl-V
Duh! :-)

Comment: Nice. This is more like a workaround... I just wonder whether the copy-paste operations preserves 100% of the document (I can think of header/footer for example)?!

Comment: After copying the document content, finding and copying the header/footer, and other configuration things that aren't "content".  I can't count how many times I've had to do things with work-related documents to "unlock" things that were needlessly locked out because management/execs don't understand the toys they're playing with.